# 3D Touch Quick Action launches black screen. UiNavigationController->UITableViewController-> UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

The app that I am working on has a UITableViewController embedded in a UINavigationController. Tapping on cells in the UITableViewController presents other UIViewControllers. I am trying to implement 3D touch in an iOS app so that the user can directly access one of the UIViewControllers from the home screen. Everything works fine except that when I tap on the link on the home screen, I get a black screen (except for the navigation bar). Here is the relevant code from the `AppDelegate`:

```
func handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) -> Bool {
    var handled = false
    guard ShortcutIdentifier(fullType: shortcutItem.type) != nil else { return false }
    guard let shortCutType = shortcutItem.type as String? else { return false }

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var vc = UIViewController()
    switch (shortCutType) {
    case ShortcutIdentifier.Tables.type:
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TableVC") as! StatTableViewController
        handled = true
        break
    case ShortcutIdentifier.ChiSquare.type:
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Chisquare") as! CSViewController
        handled = true
        break
    case ShortcutIdentifier.PowerContinuous.type:
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PowerCont") as! PowerContViewController
        handled = true
        break
    case ShortcutIdentifier.PowerDichotomous.type:
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PowerDichot") as! PowerDichotViewController
        handled = true
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    let navVC = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    navVC.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    //        navVC.show(vc, sender: self)  // Same result

    return handled
}
```

I'm reasonably sure that I'm getting to the correct `UIViewController` each time, but the screen is black. I can navigate back to the `UITableViewController`, where I can then segue back to the `UIViewController` and it works just fine. So it is clearly something in the presentation of the window that is messed up.

Thanks in advance for any and all advice.

Comment: It might be not getting data to show on the screen. check your data source using break point.

Comment: In the `UIViewController` you open, can you debug and check what all methods get called by either using break points or adding `UIAlertView`. Does `viewDidLoad` get called? Does `viewDidAppear`? What is happening inside the opened `UIViewController`?

Comment: As far as I can tell none of the lifecycle methods get called in the UIViewController that is presented from the AppDelegate. I put breaks in `viewDidLoad` in all 6 of them just in case they were mis-targeted. Also, when the  UIViewControllers are accessed via segue from the UITableViewController, all the lifecycle methods are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in my `info.plist` file. I had mistakenly thought that `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` as a prefix for the `UIApplicationShortcutItemType` would be my bundle identifier. It wasn't, so replacing `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` with my explicit bundle identifier did the trick.

Thanks for the comments, which eventually led to my finding the answer.